# Can't start docker container with Keycloak 16, exited with code 1

Tags: docker, keycloak

I'm a newbie with docker, today I'm trying to start my docker container with keycloak without success, I haven't made any change to the container and it just doesn't want to start up.
Here is the docker log error:

```
*** JBossAS process (188) received TERM signal ***
User with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'
```

The container is not inside any volume, and it was created using the command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.0
```

Comment: The full log can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/iNEyQuNg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it as well and the user account was not created. I believe that is as a result of the fact that the default 16.x.x and below are all based on wildfly and not quarkus. The new quarkus version supports these environment variables for setting up the initial admin user and is the .x preview version from 16.x.x and below.

It is only from 17.x.x onwards that quarkus is fully supported in the default version and is no longer a .x preview version. Link [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/index.html#quarkus-distribution-is-now-fully-supported)

I tested this hypothesis by running the same command but only changing the version of keycloak to 17.x.x and adding the state the server should run in and that run fine. The documentation for this is [here](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker)

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.0 start-dev`

Also note that the admin login is now at `http://localhost:8080/admin` instead of `http://localhost:8080/auth` in the new version.